# Need a count based on two cells, but one is integer and one is a string - EXCEL

Tags: excel, countif

I want to get a count of the number of cells in Column A that have 'ios', but only if the cell in Column B is blank. It gets tricky because Column A would be a string, but Column B would be an integer. My current clause returns a 0, which isn't right. I need to have Excel recognize my column B as being blank, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried variations of both of the below:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A13563,"ios",B2:B13563," ")
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2:A13563)="ios")*(LEN(B2:B13563)=0))
```

Comment: try changing the `" "` to `""` otherwise it is looking for a space, but if it is truly empty this will not work as it is looking for an empty string and not a blank cell.

Comment: The SUPRODUCT is the most reliable when dealing with blanks.

Comment: Ahh, the " " was the culprit. Thank you!